# Grant CREATE TABLE permission to MySQL User

Tags: mysql, permissions, create-table, sql-grant

I have a database that is shared between some users, and I want to manage their permissions on this.

I want to give permission for creating a new table, and accessing (select, insert, update, delete) to that table of course, to a user that doesn't have full permission on the database (only he has SELECT access to some tables).

So, I executed this query:

```
GRANT CREATE ON eh1 TO user1
```

Then, when I logged in with that user and tried to create a new table, I got this error:

> 1142 - CREATE command denied to user 'user1'@'localhost' for table 'folan'

What is the problem here? How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

The problem solved partially by changing the command to this:

`GRANT CREATE ON eh1.* TO user1`

Now there is another problem, that the user1 cannot select or insert into the newly created table. The reason is understandable, but is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use as per below-

```
GRANT CREATE ON eh1.* TO user1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1_password';
```

Note: '%' will provide access from all ips, so we should provide rights to specific ip instead of all ips, so change '%' with any ip like '191.161.3.1'

If user need select/insert/update/delete/create rights then syntax will be -

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE ON eh1.* TO user1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1_password';
```

Update as per user requirement:

```
GRANT CREATE ON eh1.* TO user1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1_password';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON eh1.table1 TO user1@'%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON eh1.table2 TO user1@'%';
```

Comment: Yes, that worked, but there is still a problem. The user cannot select rows from the created table.

Comment: first check what rights user need and assign all required rights..if user need to check tables data and insert/update/delete them then rights will be as I am updating in my answer..

Comment: I don't want to permit the user to access all tables in database. Only some tables, and tables created by him.

Comment: then you can assign create rights to full db like eh1.* and other rights to only specific tables like eh1.table1.

Comment: But I don't know what will be the name of his table

Comment: As per my knowlege there is no table owner concept in mysql, so you have to list out on which table you want to provide access to whom.

Comment: OK, it seems there is no way. This is because of poor privilege system of mysql.

Comment: If you are getting appropriate answer here then you can choose it as accepted answer..... :)

Answer (score 4):

Following [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html), correct syntax is

```
GRANT CREATE ON eh1.* TO user1
```

With eh1 a database.

If you don't use ".*", your database is considered a table.

Comment: Yes, that worked, but there is still a problem. The user cannot select rows from the created table.